# UIButton not changing image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage

I'm trying to create a "like" button for my app. When I press the button, I want it to change to a second image, and when I press it again I went it to change back to the first image.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func sendLike(sender: UIButton) {

    if let _ = UIImage(named:"pinkLike.png") {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"like.png"), forState: .Normal)
    }

    if let _ = UIImage(named:"like.png") {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"pinkLike.png"), forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

For some reason this line of code works how I want it to:

```
if let _ = UIImage(named:"like.png") {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"pinkLike.png"), forState: .Normal)
    }
```

But when I press the button again, this line doesn't change it back:

```
if let _ = UIImage(named:"pinkLike.png") {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"like.png"), forState: .Normal)
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set both of those image in Normal state, so your `"like.png"` will always override `"pinkLike.png"` image.

You need to put `"pinkLike.png"` in different state.

```
if let _ = UIImage(named:"pinkLike.png") {
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"like.png"), forState: .Selected)
}
```

and change your selected state before setting the image. So your code will be like this.

```
@IBAction func sendLike(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
    if let _ = UIImage(named:"pinkLike.png") {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"like.png"), forState: .Normal)
    }

    if let _ = UIImage(named:"like.png") {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"pinkLike.png"), forState: .Selected)
    }
}
```